# iPhone: Sending raw bytes to bluetooth accessory without pairing

Tags: iphone, sdk, bluetooth, byte

Assuming i build an accessory using "Made for iPhone" program
is it possible to just send raw bytes to a bluetooth receiver without having to pair with accessory or any other "hand-shake"?

the accessory can only receive it cannot transmit

thank you

Comment: I am pretty sure the bluetooth protocol works by 2 devices agreeing on using a set of frequencies to communicate over. They then proceed to send some data, switch the frequency, send some more data etc. This makes Bluetooth quite secure. The caveat is that they must adhere to a relationship were one is the master and the other is the slave, the slave must send data using the masters clock. This means that the only time a bluetooth device can be contacted by something not an already know master or slave, is when it is in pairing mode. I really hope what you are asking is not possible:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have seen if you use the GameKit to connect / send data between devices , Explicit Pairing is not required.